# Jest testing that a React class method was called by componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write a test to assert that my class method is being called when the componentWillMount method fires when the component renders.

I have tried the Jest documentation in addition to researching this online.  From the answers I've found (including on here) there seemed to be 2 possible methods of doing this.

The first was to:

- shallow render the component
- create a jest.fn of the class method I want to test,
- call componentWillMount using wrapper.instance().componentWIllMount
- assert that the method was called once

The second was to spy on the method I'm expecting to be called:

- shallow render the component
- set up the spy and assign to a constant e.g. functionSpy
- call componentWillMount
- assert the functionSpy was called how ever many times

The refresh method definitely fires whenever the component is rendered so I just need to work out how I can reflect this in a test.

The code base I am working on is for a civil service system so have to be really careful what I disclose, hopefully this will be enough for explaining the problem I'm having..

The class is structured:

```
  export class Search extends AnErrorComponent {

    static propTypes = {
       .....
    };

    state = {
       .....
    }

    componentWillMount(){
       this.refresh();
    }

    refresh = () => {
       .....
    } // This is the method I'm trying to test 
                               but can't seem to access/test.

    search = () => {
       .....
    }

    //etc

    render(){
       return(
          ...
       );
    }
  }
```

To test this I've tried:

```
describe('Search component', () => {

    it("should call the refresh method when the page loads", () => {
        const store = makeStore();
        const wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store}/>);
        wrapper.instance().refresh = jest.fn();
        wrapper.update();
        wrapper.instance().componentWillMount;
        expect(wrapper.instance().refresh).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

});
```

The result of running this test is:

```
 ● Search component › should call the refresh method when the page loads

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
```

I also tried:

```
describe('Search component', () => {

    it("should call the refresh method when the page loads", () => {
        const store = makeStore();
        const wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store}/>);
        const refreshSpy = spyOn(Search.prototype, 'refresh');
        wrapper.instance().componentWillMount;
        expect(refreshSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

});
```

I get the error:

```
● Search component › should call the refresh method when the page loads

    refresh() method does not exist
```

This refers to the spy I tried to create.

I've double checked and I have imported the Search component in addition to the component it inherits from.  I have also tried using mount instead of shallow rendering; however to make this work I had to wrap the component in a provider otherwise an error would be thrown e.g.

```
<provider store={store}>
  <Search />
</provider>
```

I still got the same results after when using mount and wrapping the component in a provider.  Due to the spy error I tried console logging wrapper.instance() in both tests and noted that none of the class methods are listed anywhere if this helps?  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. (This is the first question I've posted on here so hopefully this makes sense).

** Just to add, when using `jest.spyOn()` I get `TypeError: jest.spyOn is not a function`. I am using Jest 21.2.1 which I read should allow me to use `jest.spyOn()` as it was added in V19. **

Comment: But you're not calling the method? `wrapper.instance().componentWillMount()`

Comment: I think your method is good, you just need to replace `wrapper.instance().componentWillMount` by `wrapper.instance().componentWillMount()`

Comment: `when the componentWillMount method fires when the component renders` this is not true:
`UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render()`
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: I don't know why people post questions and then disappears without any response. :/

Comment: Thanks OlivierBoissé , I tried updating the test with componentWillMount() and have realised that I hadn't called it properly.  I'm now getting a new error: TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).componentWillMount is not a function.  This seems to be part of the problem I'm noticing, I can't seem to use the class methods?

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount` is a method on the class instance, not a property. You need to call it to trigger the effect:

```
describe('Search component', () => {

    it("should call the refresh method when the page loads", () => {
        const store = makeStore();
        const wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store}/>);
        wrapper.instance().refresh = jest.fn();
        wrapper.update();
        wrapper.instance().componentWillMount();                     // Calling the method
        expect(wrapper.instance().refresh).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Clarity, I tried updating the test with componentWillMount() and have realised that I hadn't called it properly. I'm now getting a new error: TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).componentWillMount is not a function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `componentWillMount` and `spyOn` the `refresh` function by [Mock Implementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations)

```
describe('Search component', () => {
  const store = makeStore();
  const wrapper = shallow(<Search store={store}/>);
  let refresh;
  beforeAll(() => {
     refresh = jest.spyOn(Search.prototype, 'refresh').mockImplementation(() => true);
  });
  it("should call the refresh method when the page loads", () => {
    wrapper.instance().componentWillMount();
    expect(refresh.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    refresh.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried this but I'm still getting TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).componentWillMount is not a function.  I initially also used jest.spyOn but got the to following TypeError: jest.spyOn is not a function.  I got this when running this test too?

Comment: Can you post the full code for the test spec? I would like to run it in my local machine @Ajay233